# Extjs Combobox renderto div declared in an XTemplate

Tags: extjs

Can I apply on a combobox in extjs "renderTo" to a div that is created in a XTemplate?
This XTemplate also create the title of a panel.
Thanks
Lets' say i have:

```
var tpl = new XTemplate('<div id="myDiv"></div>');
...
tpl.apply(...);
...
var combobox = new Ext.Form.ComboBox({
  renderTo: 'myDiv'
});
```

is this correct written?

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: I think that is correct. I added you an working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<div id="div-id">My Div</div>'
        );
        tpl.append(Ext.getBody(), {});

        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data : [
                {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
                {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
                {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
                //...
            ]
        });

        // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            renderTo: "div-id"
        });
    }
});
```